executing python script by php in apache2 webserver
I have a python script that needs to executed by php in apache2 webserver, but before executing the script , navidate to the pyrthon directory, setup the python virtual environment and install all dependencies from php file.I am getting permission denied
// Print current working directory for debugging
echo "Current working directory: " . getcwd() . "<br>";

// Change the directory to the project directory
//chdir($projectDir);
// Attempt to change directory to the project directory
if (!chdir($projectDir)) {
    echo "Failed to change directory to $projectDir\n";
    exit(1);
}

echo "Changed directory to $projectDir\n";
/*
// Step 1: Check if virtual environment exists, create if not
if (!file_exists($venvPath)) {
    $createVenvCommand = "python3 -m venv $venvPath";
    $createVenvOutput = shell_exec("$createVenvCommand 2>&1");
    if ($createVenvOutput === null) {
        echo "Failed to create virtual environment:\n";
        echo "Command: $createVenvCommand\n";
        exit(1);
    } else {
        echo "Virtual environment created successfully.\n";
    }
} else {
    echo "Virtual environment already exists.\n";
}

// Step 2: Install dependencies
$installDepsCommand = "$venvPath/bin/pip install -r $requirementPath";
$installDepsOutput = shell_exec("$installDepsCommand 2>&1");
if ($installDepsOutput === null) {
    echo "Failed to install dependencies:\n";
    echo "Command: $installDepsCommand\n";
    exit(1);
} else {
    echo "Dependencies installed successfully.\n";
}

// Step 3: Execute the Python script
$executeScriptCommand = "echo '4255' | sudo -S sh -c 'python3 $pyScript --slug 'utopiaa-farmland''";
$scriptOutput = shell_exec("$executeScriptCommand 2>&1");
if ($scriptOutput === null) {
    echo "Failed to execute Python script:\n";
    echo "Command: $executeScriptCommand\n";
    exit(1);
} else {
    echo "Python script executed successfully:\n" . $scriptOutput;
}

exit(0);


I added www-data user to host group(i,e ubuntu group) owning the project directory.
changed the permission of the project directory to 777.

By the project directory, you mean the Python or PHP directory? Are you sure that the ubuntu group owns the permission to execute the script? and finally, dumping your command and executing it manually on your terminal, works?

Hii, project directory is where my python script resides.  total 140
drwxrwxr-x 3 subrathkumar subrathkumar   4096 Jul 18 15:47 facebook
-rw-rw-r-- 1 subrathkumar subrathkumar   1072 Jul 18 15:47 LICENSE
-rw-rw-r-- 1 subrathkumar subrathkumar   1589 Jul 18 15:47 linux_requirement.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 subrathkumar subrathkumar 119485 Jul 18 15:47 property_summary.ipynb
Here user is "subrathkumar". Can please give logic of performing the above opearation. I am trying it from 1week .Manual execution works perfectly

what is the output of this command getent group ubuntu
